# Scala overload constructor with mutable List of different type

Tags: scala

I am trying to overload a constructor with mutable list of Int and Long , it mentions that the method is already defined.
I need `updateList` to be either `mutable.MutableList[Int]` or `mutable.MutableList[Long]`

```
object PercentileDistribution {
  def apply(updateList: mutable.MutableList[Int], percentileDistribution: PercentileDistribution): PercentileDistribution = {
    updateList.foreach { x =>
      percentileDistribution.update(x)
    }
    percentileDistribution
  }

  def apply(updateList: mutable.MutableList[Long], percentileDistribution: PercentileDistribution): PercentileDistribution = {
    updateList.foreach { x =>
      percentileDistribution.update(x)
    }
    percentileDistribution
  }
}
```

Being new to scala I am facing some issues, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly refers to the upcasting that is happening in your code.
An `Int` can be represented as a `Long` hence you have essentially written the same method with one methods parameter being the upcasted version of the parameter of the other apply method.

You can simply use the apply method that has the `MutableList[Long]` type and remove the one with `Int`.

Follow this [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html) from the official scala docs and you will get a good idea as to how types behave in Scala

Answer (score 1):

The error refers to [*type erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The other answer incorrectly states that it is related to casting (although type erasure can lead to casting-related problems).

A quick example done in a Scala REPL session:

```
scala> class Foo {
     |   def bar(list: List[Int]) = "ints"
     |   def bar(list: List[String]) = "strings"
     | }
<console>:12: error: double definition:
def bar(list: List[Int]): String at line 11 and
def bar(list: List[String]): String at line 12
have same type after erasure: (list: List)String
         def bar(list: List[String]) = "strings"
             ^
```

The message here is saying that both `bar` methods will have a type signature like `def bar(list: List): String` in the compiled output; type erasure is taking away the `[Int]` and `[String]` parameters, making the two methods indistinguishable. It's an annoyance you just have to put up with if you're running code on the JVM.

My recommended workaround is to distinguish the methods by their names, e.g. instead of `apply` you might call it `forInts` and `forLongs`.

Also note that type erasure causes another problem:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).isInstanceOf[List[String]]
<console>:11: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type List[Int] cannot also be a List[String] (the underlying of List[String]) (but still might match its erasure)
       List(1,2,3).isInstanceOf[List[String]]
                               ^
res5: Boolean = true
```

and

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) match {
     |   case l: List[String] => l // you'd think this shouldn't match, but it does
     | }
<console>:12: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type List[Int] cannot also be a List[String] (the underlying of List[String]) (but still might match its erasure)
         case l: List[String] => l // you'd think this shouldn't match, but it does
                 ^
res2: List[Int] with List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> res2.head
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
  ... 33 elided
```

Since in the compiled bytecode, `List[Int]` and `List[String]` are both only represented as `List`, the runtime can't actually distinguish between the two, so an `isInstanceOf` check may provide the wrong answer, possibly leading to ClassCastExceptions as it tries to treat an `Int` as a `String`.

In your case you might get away with it, since it is safe to cast an `Int` to a `Long`, but it'd be best to avoid unchecked casting altogether.